# Sending complex object GET vs POST

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, get

I wonder what the best way is to send a complex object when it is only for finding data purposes. I have a grid where paging, filtering , sorting etc will be done sever side. So I have to send all that data with each request.

```
public class DataConfiguratorDto
{
    [Required]
    public Paging Paging { get; set; }

    public Sorting Sorting { get; set; }

    public IList<Filtering> FlitersList { get; set; }
}

public enum FilterCondition
{
    Equals,
    Contains,
    MoreThan,
    LessThan,
}

public class Paging
{
    public int RowNumberStart { get; set; }

    [GreaterThan(nameof(RowNumberStart))]
    public int RowNumberEnd { get; set; }
}

public class Filtering
{
    [Required]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public object FilterValue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public FilterCondition FilterCondition { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public FilterType FilterType { get; set; }
}

public class Sorting
{
    [Required]
    public SortOption SortOption;

    [Required]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
}

public enum SortOption
{
    Asc,
    Desc
}

public enum FilterType
{
    And,
    Or
}
```

Now I could use POST but isn't it breaking it's purpose ?

What would be the best option to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use a post, sending the complex object in the body (as JSON for example).

per W3.org

"The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI."

"The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line."

See [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) for more info.